# CGImage causing memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I am creating a cgimage using this code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(size*2, size*2));
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[[SKColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1] setFill];
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, size*2, size*2));

UIImage *textureImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:textureImage];

SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
```

Clearly it is the source of the problem.

I tried wrapping it in an autorelease block and I tried cfreleasing the cgimageref, but I'm using ARC so those don't really do anything. What is going on??

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably need a call to [UIGraphicsEndImageContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsEndImageContext) to clean things up somewhat.

Also, set your "`textureImage`" to nil after you create your SKTexture object and see if that helps a bit.